# Why is console.log logging $(this).data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is my console logging the $(this).data? When i console log the variable i get undefined.

I need access to `chartType` to move along with the code:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("points")){
     chartType = $(this).data('chart-type');

     console.log($(this));
     console.log(chartType);
}
```

Heres what it logs
(Stack Overflow wont let me put what it consoles on the first line, but it exists)

```
undefined
```

Comment: Where is this happening?

Comment: Might not be  sure what you mean.  But it is happening within a click function.  And it is outputting the undefined in the console.  Sorry if this is not what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jquery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)   to select the attribute.

```
if ($(this).hasClass("points")){
         chartType = $(this).attr('data-custom-value');

         console.log($(this));
         console.log(chartType);
    }
```

Comment: This still does not work for me.   Here is my html for my button.

Comment: <a class="chart-btn points" href="#" data-custom-value="week">

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Thanks All...Appreciated!

Comment: Just wondering why i received a negative rating for my question if anyone could explain.  Thanks beforehand.  Jason